# How are Aryavarta, Brahmavarta and Madhyadesa defined?

Tags: geography

I believe Aryavarta contains Madhyadesa which contains Brahmavarta.

Where are these defined geographically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Brahmavarta lies between the two rivers Saraswati and Drishadvati.

> Manu Smriti 2.17. That land, created by the gods, which lies between
>   the two divine rivers Sarasvati and Drishadvati, the (sages) call
>   Brahmavarta

- Madhyadesha

  > 2.21. That (country) which (lies) between the Himavat and the Vindhya (mountains) to the east of Prayaga and to the west of Vinasana (the
  >   place where the river Sarasvati disappears) is called Madhyadesa (the
  >   central region).

- And, Aryavarta is the land between Himalayas and the Vindhya mountains.

> 2.22. But (the tract) between those two mountains (just mentioned), which (extends) as far as the eastern and the western oceans, the wise
>   call Aryavarta (the country of the Aryans).

Similar verses from Dharma Sutras of Vashishta:

> The region east of where the Sarasvati¯ disappears, west of Kalaka
>   forest, north of Pariyatra mountains, and south of the Himalayas is
>   the land of the Aryas; 9 or else, north of the Vindhya mountains.
>
> 10 The Laws and practices of that region should be recognized as
>   authoritative everywhere, 11 but not others found in regions with Laws
>   contrary to those.*
>
> 12 According to some, the land of the Aryas is the region between the
>   Ganges and Yamuna. 13 According to others, vedic splendour extends as
>   far as the black antelope roams.
>
> (1.8-13)