# What is the extent of Aryavrata?

Tags: mahabharata, india

What is the extent of Aryavrata described in scriptures , escpecially in Mahabharata ?

Comment: himalayas to vindhyas.. sindh to brahma desh (burma) - there are 4 natural boundaries for india - mountain, desert, forest, ocean.

Comment: Duplicate of - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/38389/4732